# Website images on unusual places , Scroll bar image on bookmarks (Only Firefox)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, firefox, web

I am facing some strange issues with Firefox only and only on one of my PC's. I know these are not the issues with my website. But i am concerned more about it if my customers face this issue only with my website. I still want to confirm about it that if they are from my end or any other issue. Kindly help and provide me a better solution.

My problems are listed below:

1) Sometimes my profile image appears on other images or we can say replace my other images. Infact the profile image is also corrupted.

2) My Dropdowns sometimes shows weird design as shown in the screenshot below.

3) Scrollbar image appears on my saved bookmarks.

I have tried many solutions to resolve this. Here are the troubleshooting steps which i have already tried:

1) I disabled all of my add-on plugins.

2) I resetted my firefox.

3) I uninstalled my firefox , shut down my computer and then i reinstalled it . Still i faced this issue on my website only.

Kindly ask if you still want to know something more about it.

Thanks in advance for any help or Suggestions.

[image: Scroll bar image bug]

[image: Dropdown bug]